# Lint warns the overwritten strings in strings.xml as unused

Tags: android, android-resources, lint

I have an android library module with strings.xml declares some strings inside. Of course, these strings are used in this library.

I have an android application which has dependencies `implementation project(':thelibmodule')`. Then in this android application, I also have the same strings to overwrite the ones in the android library. So it means they are being used inside android library.

This strategy works perfectly, the overwritten strings are working perfectly. But the Lint warns that these strings in android application are unused. Why and how to fix? Should I fix the code somehow or should I fix the Lint rules?

Comment: Hmmm... looks like nobody is facing this problem, or nobody has an answer, or even nobody wants to discuss. Sad!

Comment: This because of how [UnusedResourceDetector](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/UnusedResourceDetector.java) is implemented. As far as I know, it only looks for usages in project files, not checking external libraries.
The warning should be treated as false positive and can be ignored.

But I would say that resource overriding is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Not really a bad practice. What will you do if you have the same lib for many apps, but some apps only support one language and other apps will support multiple languages? You have to do this, or can you tell me how to do as you exp?

Comment: Resource overriding can result in hard-to-find bugs. What will happen if library adds or removes positional argument in a string in a new version? You have to make sure the overridden resources match the new "contract". I see two better ways: 1. add support all required languages in the library itself (not always possible, especially if you're not a developer of that library) 2. move resources out of library and provide an interface for fetching resources (via Kotlin/Java or theme attributes), and implement it on the app's side.

Comment: @italankin we don't have to make sure overridden resources match the new contract if we have a specific resources only for being overridden, the contract is there, but we can't missed because if we want a new language for that resources, we need to overwrite that. But yes, I agree with you that your solution (2) looks promising, although it requires some more effort, but yeah, I think I can do that to avoid the warnings. Thanks a lot.